# Advanced Merge File Content

Tags: file, merge

I am under Windows and I am using Sublime2 Text Editor (i can download and use any other software) or PHP script.

Now, I am searching for solution to advance merge two files (or lines at one file, no matter). `KEY` - is the same part of two files

sourcefileone.txt:

```
KEY|CCC
```

sortcefiletwo.txt

```
KEY|BBB
```

Need to merge and receive this:

```
KEY|BBB|CCC
```

Any Solution? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems there is no ready solution. To solve the problem I already wrote php code that load to files in array, than `explode` them and merge in the new format at new array.